# Path change for achieving the functionality

Tags: c#, .net

I have to get version value from registry, the path is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Secon\Secon Monitor`. In that path we can see one file **CurrentVersion** which contain value.

So i did this type of coding to fetch value

There is one class file **Simregistry.cs** where all registry paths are registered.So there i registered one path as below

```
public const string SimRoot = @"Software\Secon\Secon Monitor";
```

then i accessed **'SimRoot'**  this on diferrent file

```
string keySpoPath = SpoRegistry.SimRoot;
RegistryKey regkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keySpoPath);
m_version = (string)regkey.GetValue(SpoRegistry.regValue_CurrentVersion);
```

But i need to achieve the same functionality this way .i need to register path in this way

```
public const string SimRoot = "Software\\Secon\\Secon Monitor\\";
```

instead of:

```
public const string SimRoot = @"Software\Secon\Secon Monitor";`
```

how can i achieve this by changing this code

```
string keySpoPath = SpoRegistry.SimRoot;
RegistryKey regkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keySpoPath);
m_version = (string)regkey.GetValue(SpoRegistry.regValue_CurrentVersion);
```

**i can add @ like this SpoRegistry.SimRoot+ @,,but how can i remove those two extra slashes() one after Software and one after Secon**

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why do you need to have the strings escaped?

Comment: i need to change public const string SimRoot = @"Software\Secon\Secon Monitor"; to public const string SimRoot = "Software\\Secon\\Secon Monitor\\"; 

so what changes i have to do here string keySpoPath = SpoRegistry.SimRoot;
                    RegistryKey regkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keySpoPath);
                    m_version = (string)regkey.GetValue(SpoRegistry.regValue_CurrentVersion);
to achieve the same functionality

Comment: can add @ like this SpoRegistry.SimRoot+ @,,but how can i remove those two extra slashes(\\) one after Software and one after Secon

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the strings:

```
public const string SimRoot = "Software\\Secon\\Secon Monitor\\";
```

And:

```
public const string SimRoot = @"Software\Secon\Secon Monitor";
```

Is that the first has a trailing slash (`\`).

You can simply concatenate it to your constant:

```
string keySpoPath = SpoRegistry.SimRoot + "\\";
```

Comment: what my intention is make the code changes ,in this way that i need to change public const string SimRoot = @"Software\Secon\Secon Monitor"; to public const string SimRoot = "Software\\Secon\\Secon Monitor\\"; ,,so how can i change the code

Comment: no @ symbol and this symbol (\\) is more in two sides,,how can i cut

Comment: You should find out more about what the `@` does. @"\" and "\\" are the same string in C#

Comment: can add @ like this SpoRegistry.SimRoot+ @,,but how can i remove those two extra slashes(\\) one after Software and one after Secon

Comment: Again - you don't need to. In a regular string, the `\\` are evaluated as a `\` (this is called string escaping - look it up). In a string literal (one that has a `@` in front of it), you don't need to escape the `\`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add anything more. both are same public const string SimRoot = "Software\Secon\Secon Monitor\";  and public const string SimRoot = @"Software\Secon\Secon Monitor";
 are same

Comment: this will give the information regarding my question   http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_String_Theory%E2%80%94String_literals